# Intellij not able to index gradle imported jar files, while code is compiling and running properly

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, import, jar

My application (Kotlin/JVM) is working as expected the code is compiled and ran. But unfortunately the Intellij IDEA is not able to index the libraries from a local jar, I have imported the library from the Kotlin gradle script (build.gradle.kts).

```kotlin
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation(files("../konvironment-plugin/build/libs/konvironment-plugin-0.0.1-all.jar"))
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

As you can see above application is running (in the bottom console), the library is there (at left) I can see no build errors, but the Intellij is not being able to detect classes and packages in the editor.

I did **Invalidate Caches and Restart**, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

What could I do to aware the Intellij IDEA that the jar is right there (Jar is created from shadow plugin).

Comment: Do you see this library jar listed in module's [dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html) tab? Also check the library configuration (double clicking) that the path to a library is correctly detected. If issue remains please file bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: @Andrey Yep, I can see https://imgur.com/a/xpDKBM0 yes the path is correct, hence it is shown in Project panel's external dependencies tab, as well as the build succeed and project can run.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same thing - did you every find a solution? I can see the jar listed under the gradle tab, under dependencies but it isn't listed as an external jar in the project and therefore isn't indexed.